# Is property binding still the same?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm not a `XAML` and `MVVM` expert. I would like to know if, with all latest `C#` improvements, are we still forced to write our `MVVM` properties like this:

```
private string sessionName;

public string SessionName
{
    get
    {
        return sessionName;
    }
    private set
    {
        sessionName = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SessionName));
    }
}
```

Or is there is a better way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to automatically inject code that raises the `PropertyChanged` event into property setters of classes that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` at compile time.

You can then implement your property like this:

```
public string SessionName { get; set; }
```

There is nothing in the C# language itself or the UI frameworks that saves you from having to define a backing field and explicitly raise the event in the property setter though.

Comment: Good suggestion, I would just make sure you *read the license* carefully if you plan on using Fody.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're not going to go the Fody route, you can still remove a lot of the verbosity from MVVM property definitions.

Given a base class for models / viewmodels

```
/// <summary>
/// Base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged
/// </summary>
public abstract class BindableBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // update a property value, and fire PropertyChanged event when the value is actually updated
    protected bool Set<T>(string propertyName, ref T field, T newValue)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
            return false;

        field = newValue;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    // update a property value, and fire PropertyChanged event when the value is actually updated
    // without having to pass in the property name
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        return Set(propertyName, ref field, newValue);
    }
}
```

You can now write your property definition as

```
public class Session: BindableBase
{
    private string sessionName;

    public string SessionName
    {
        get => sessionName;
        private set => Set(ref sessionName, value);
     }
}
```

Comment: Well, still need to create a private variable then the public one.